# gmdate() return the wrong time

Tags: php, time

I have an issue with gmdate(), it returns two hours less than the real timezone.

```
gmdate('H:i:s', $now)
```

I tried this :

```
date_default_timezone_get() -> return 'Europe/Paris'
```

I checked my php.ini, the timezone is correct

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

I don't really understand what happens or what is the trick, if someone can help me, I'll be grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your timezone?

Comment: @HoangHieu - this is Paris

Answer (score 4):

Well, a `gmdate` is a GMT date :) and not a date in your timezone.

> Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is **Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)**.

Try this

```
date('H:i:s', $now);   // this function is what you need.
```

And oh, What about the 2 hours thing?

> Paris, France is 2 hours ahead of Greenwich Mean Time

**[Reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=paris%20and%20gmt%20difference)**

Comment: Damm, you're fast hh. From the manual: Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Answer (score 0):

Well, a gmdate is a GMT date :) and not a date in your timezone.(copied)

Use Date('Z'), I hope this help

> gmdate('d/m/Y, H:i:s',$now + date("Z"))